# Writing a function that will break out of a for loop when return is pressed.

Tags: matlab, loops, keyboard-events

I am writing a matlab script that will perform calculations in a for loop, but would like it to break out of the for loop when 'return' is entered. I found a function that will listen for keystrokes and modified it to know when 'return' is pressed, but I can't figure out how to make it control what is going on in the main script.

Pseudo Code:

```
h_fig = figure;
set(h_fig,'KeyPressFcn',@myfun)

for ii = 1:50
        break when enter is pressed
end


    function y = myfun(src,event)
        y = strcmp(event.Key,'return');
        %disp(event.Key);
        if y == 1
            fprintf('Enter key pressed')
            return
        end
    end
```

Comment: What do you mean by *controlling*  the main script?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are creating the window only so you can capture the return key press. If this is the case, there is a better alternative: [`kbhit`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30622-non-wait-detection-of-keyboard-input--including-mex-implementation-) (in Octave a similar function with the same name comes built-in). Simply copy the `kbhit.m` file from that File Exchange submission to your current folder (or any directory that you can add to your MATLAB path using `addpath`), and do as follows:

```
kbhit('init');
for ii = 1:50
   if kbhit == 13
      break
   end
   % computations here...
end
```

If you want to use a window anyway, the right way to do so is to poll the ["CurrentCharacter" property of the figure window](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#property_d119e285702):

```
h_fig = figure;
set(h_fig,'CurrentCharacter','') % use this if the figure has been around for longer, to reset the last key pressed
for ii = 1:50
   drawnow % sometimes events are not handled unless you add this
   if double(get(h_fig,'CurrentCharacter'))==13
      break
   end
   % computations here...
end
```

I could not get the above code to work in Octave, it seems that it doesn't update figure properties even with `drawnow`, not sure why. But I'm fairly sure the above works with MATLAB.